# c# multidimesional array iteration

Tags: c#, arrays

i have an multidimensional `string` array that looks like this :

example data:

```
{{20.07.2020 06:00, 20.07.2020 07:00, 150},{20.07.2020 07:00, 20.07.2020 08:00, 130}, {20.07.2020 08:00, 20.07.2020 09:00, 15}, {20.07.2020 09:00, 20.07.2020 10:00, 180}, {20.07.2020 10:00, 20.07.2020 11:00, 100}} etc.
```

and need to validate the the value part of array (3rd item of an inner array) :

```
1. if value is empty, replace it with 0 and extract this array into a new ZeroArray ( which will contain all the arrays with empty values)
2. if value(i) is greater or smaller than value(i+1) for 50% or more, extract this array into a new ExtremeArray(which will contain all the arrays with extreme values)
3. get the sum of all values in array of arrays
```

Can anyone give me a help me on how to work with the multidimensional array and get the needed results?
Thank You all in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of data? `[DateTime,DateTime, value]` looks more ike a class (tuple, record etc.) not an inner array. Finally, what `ZeroArray` and `ExtremeArray` look like?

Comment: It's an array consisting of inner array which have start date, end date and value corresponding to this period. for example [[20.07.2020 14:00, 20.07.2020 15:00, 170][20.07.2020 15:00, 20.07.2020 16:00, 120] etc.] (i don't know its length, just the length of the inner array which always consists of 3)

Comment: FYI, c# has both [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) and [multidimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) . It is not obvious witch one you are actually using.

Comment: I'm sorry, i am new at c#. Well, i was just told that i would get an array that looks like the example above, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only asked for a hint (and this feels suspiciously like a homework problem...) I think a good hint is that you're going to have to use two counters.  One for traversing the first part of the array, then the next for traversing the inner array.  These counters are going to be nested.  Essentially, you have a problem like:

```
Count from 0 to 5.
But each time you increment a number, count from 20 to 25.
```

so you'd do something like:

```
for (var outerCount = 0; outerCount <= 5; outerCount++)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Counting {outerCount}");

  for (var innerCount = 20; innerCount <= 25; innerCount++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"\tCounting {innerCount}");
  }
}
```

### Output

```
Counting 0
    Counting 20
    Counting 21
    Counting 22
    Counting 23
    Counting 24
    Counting 25
Counting 1
    Counting 20
    Counting 21
    Counting 22
    Counting 23
    Counting 24
    Counting 25
Counting 2
    Counting 20
    Counting 21
    Counting 22
    Counting 23
    Counting 24
    Counting 25
Counting 3
    Counting 20
    Counting 21
    Counting 22
    Counting 23
    Counting 24
    Counting 25
Counting 4
    Counting 20
    Counting 21
    Counting 22
    Counting 23
    Counting 24
    Counting 25
Counting 5
    Counting 20
    Counting 21
    Counting 22
    Counting 23
    Counting 24
    Counting 25
```

Comment: But i should iterate till the end of the arrays length. And how to extract only the last item in each inner array to work on?

Comment: each array has a .Length property that you can use to bound your for loops.  Then you'll both know when to stop iterating, and when you're at the last element in the array to extract the last value. :)

Comment: Thanks, i am just still not sure how to declare the last elements of the inner array to compute these three functions?

Comment: And also, how to convert it, since it is a string array, and i need to work with integers.

Comment: Modify the code I wrote to just print out everything inside of your array.  Then post that answer and I bet you'll start seeing the pattern.  The first step in all this is to learn how to just iterate over the elements in the array.  Then it's a very easy modification to the code to set the variables.

Comment: I tried an example: `string[,] CsvArray = new string[,] { { "28.09.1996. 20:00", "28.09.1996. 21:00", "150"}, {"10.10.1876. 23:00", "10.10.1876. 00:00", "239" }, {"11.12.2020. 13:00", "11.12.2020. 14:00", "80" } };
            for (var outerCount = 0; outerCount < CsvArray.GetLength(1); outerCount++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Counting {outerCount}");

                for (var innerCount = 0; innerCount < CsvArray.GetLength(0); innerCount++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tCounting {innerCount}");
                }
            }`

Comment: - and the output is : `Counting 0
        Counting 0
        Counting 1
        Counting 2
Counting 1
        Counting 0
        Counting 1
        Counting 2
Counting 2
        Counting 0
        Counting 1
        Counting 2` - but i still don't know how to get to the last element in the inner array, that's now just the syntax problem.

Comment: And i still cannot work with it cause it's a string array, and i need int.

Comment: Now, when you encounter an element you know should be an int, you can call: `int myInt = System.Convert.Int32("123");`

Comment: is it possible to convert this way the whole array at once? or even better, convert only last item of each inner array all together? cause i don't how how many items will my array have in total.

Comment: You can convert it with a complicated LINQ statement, but I'd imagine your CS Professor would know you didn't come up with that answer.  They're probably looking for you to create an array of the same size, and write the converted data one at a time as you iterate through the source array.

Comment: Can you write the code for converting through iteration, please? I am still struggling with that part.